# ZFS: How to reduce frequency of or prevent txg_sync

Tags: debian, zfs

I have a small home sever running with Debian Buster where I have a ZFS filesystem (`ZFS: Loaded module v0.7.12-2+deb10u2, ZFS pool version 5000, ZFS filesystem version 5`) with a RAID.

As the server is sometimes not used for days I have configured a autoshutdown script which shuts down the server if my 2 big WD red hard disks are in standby for more than 45 minutes (not the system hard disk). Now I figured out that the server is not shutting down anymore as both drives are only a few minutes in standby before getting active again. I tested with `iotop` and figured out that ZFS with the command `txg_sync` is waking them up. Even if no other process is writing or reading anything on the drives.

I did also a check with `fatrace -c` after changing to the directory where the datapool is mounted. There is no output at the time as the command `txg_sync` pops up and wakes the drives. Update: As it seems that fatrace is not working properly with ZFS.

I now used `iosnoop`from and now know that dm_crypt is writing on my disks regularly. My underlying drives are encrypted with LUKS.

```
./iosnoop -d 8,16
Tracing block I/O. Ctrl-C to end.
COMM         PID    TYPE DEV      BLOCK        BYTES     LATms
dmcrypt_writ 1895   W    8,16     2080476248   4096    6516.10
dmcrypt_writ 1895   W    8,16     3334728264   4096    6516.14
dmcrypt_writ 1895   W    8,16     2080429048   16384      0.16
dmcrypt_writ 1895   W    8,16     3334728272   20480      0.21
dmcrypt_writ 1895   W    8,16     2080476256   20480      0.16
dmcrypt_writ 1895   W    8,16     3328225336   16384      0.20
```

What is the reason for that and how can I prevent this occuring?

Comment: *Now I figured out that the server is not shutting down anymore...*  So what changed?  Something is likely accessing or updating data on those drives - just opening a file descriptor in the file system can be enough to cause the access time of the inode to be updated, causing a write to disk.

Comment: I don't know. It may be related to any update. No other major changes where made. I can not directly reproduce when this occured the first time. I edited my post as I now even checked with `fatrace -c` which does not show anything at the time the disks are waked up.

Comment: Questions about system administration are better suited to [UNIX.se] or Server Fault rather than Stack Overflow. (There's a reason your accepted answer links to Server Fault).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://github.com/openzfs/zfs/issues/8537#issuecomment-477361010

> @niksfirefly if the pool is being written to then you should expect to see cpu and I/O by consumed by the txg_sync thread. How much will depend on your specific hardware, the pool configuration, which features/properties are enabled, and your workload. This may be normal for your circumstances.

And maybe this link is helpful too:
https://serverfault.com/questions/661336/slow-performance-due-to-txg-sync-for-zfs-0-6-3-on-ubuntu-14-04

How to check disk I/O utilization per process:

```
cut -d" " -f 1,2,42 /proc/*/stat | sort -n -k +3
```

> Those fields are PID, command and cumulative IO-wait ticks. This will show your hot processes, though only if they are still running. (You probably want to ignore your filesystem journalling threads.)

(from https://serverfault.com/a/466342/580935)

Answer (score 1):

Another note on ZFS.
I'm on Manjaro 20210101 with kernel 5.4 and had a high load on *txg_sync* in the last weeks.

According to /var/log/pacman.log

> [2020-12-31T08:58:24+0100] [ALPM] upgraded zfs-utils (0.8.5-2 -> 2.0.0-2)
> [2020-12-31T08:58:24+0100] [ALPM] upgraded linux54-zfs (0.8.5-10 -> 2.0.0-6)

Since that time, the *txg_sync* process has also restored peace.

Under Debian, the use of ZFS (and its versions) is certainly solved somewhat differently.

Answer (score 1):

You can change the frequency of tgx_sync operations in Linux with

```
echo 15 > /sys/module/zfs/parameters/zfs_txg_timeout
```

for 15 seconds for eg, or set it in **/etc/modprobe.d/zfs.conf**:

```
options zfs zfs_txg_timeout=$your_value
```